# Heirachical grid group by features and userstotries ,subuserstories and task

Tags: rally, code-rally

I have rally data in which userstories is associated with features.
I want to show heirarchical features and usetstories ,subuserstories and tasks up to n level. Is it possible to do ?

eg.

feature1
  - userstory 1  - subuserstory1 -
                                   - subsubuserstory1 - task
                                                      - task

```
                               - subsubuserstory1 - task
               subuserstory2-
                               - subsubuserstory3 - task
                               - subsubuserstory4 - task
```

- userstory 2
               - subuserstory 3
                                 - subsubuserstory5
                                 - subsubuserstory6
- userstory 3
               -subuserstory 4
                                - subsubuserstory7
                                - subsubuserstory8

Also i want to show Testcase count for each userstory/substory in rally app .

Answer (score 0):

See [Rally.ui.grid.TreeGrid](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.TreeGrid).
There is a full example of a tree grid that starts on PI/Feature level and includes associated stories and tasks [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/bulk-editable-tree-grid).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: It works for me.

Now I can see the nested userstories under feature.
1.I want feature name instead of feature id where we toggle.
2.agreegate Test Case Count by its nested user stories test cases.
                                        TestCaseCount :
eg.    feature1                        (5)
     >  userstory 1                     1
     >  userstory 2                     2
      > userstory 3                     2
 feature 2                             10
       >userstory 3                    4
       >userstory 4                    6

can we do like this way?